# How do you generate a CAD geometry of randomly oriented objects?

Tags: matlab, draw, cad, solidworks

How can one generate CAD geometries of randomly oriented and randomly sized objects (3D)?  I need to model randomly sized and randomly oriented rectangles--thousands to millions of them.

I have not yet come across any CAD tools that have =rand() functions that can be inputted into dimensions.  Is one way perhaps to have a CAD program import a CSV file of these randomly generated parameter values?

Answer (score 0):

In SolidWorks, you can have model parameters (dimension lengths/angles, constraints, etc.) stored in an Excel spreadsheet called a *Design Table*. Each row in the spreadsheet will represent a different configuration of your model, and each column a different parameter. You can use Excel's built-in capabilities or an export-capable tool of your choosing to generate the configurations according to your desired distribution. I don't recall off the top of my head the easiest way to get a large number of instances with different configurations into the same assembly, but you haven't really told us what you're trying to accomplish so I can't give you specific recommendations anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific CAD tool then you can often find documentation on the internal file format. With a little experimentation you can sometimes write a small external program that will generate the header of the CAD file and then loop thousands or millions of times generating each individual object. Finally you generate the lines needed to complete the file. That can sometimes be easier than trying to force a tool to do something the designers never expected. And this might let you use the software of your choice to generate the file.

I would suggest starting small. Use the CAD tool to create a file with two or three of your rectangles. Save and inspect the contents of the file to see that it matches your understanding of the needed format. Then try externally creating what should be the same file and verify your version is correctly accepted.

You might consider that some tool designers never expected someone to want thousands or millions of anything. I would suggest sneaking up on the problem. Try doubling the number of items, check this works as expected and then repeat this process again and again until either you successfully get to millions or until you find the CAD tool won't be able to handle this.